# Session with node.js and routing at once

Tags: node.js, session

It's my 1st time using session with node.
On my app, I've something like this...

```
app.use(express.cookieParser());
app.use(express.session({secret: config.sessionSecret}));

app.get('/', routes.index);
```

Ok so far. But at my index.js I need to perform some session stuffs...

```
exports.index = function(req, res){
    var sessionID = req.session.ID;
    if(sessionID == null)
    {
        req.session.ID = uuid.v4();
        console.log("Cookie Built");
    }
    else
    {
        console.log("Cookie Retrieved : " + sessionID );
    }
});
```

But it's not works...and I don't know how to make it works...any clue ? It's throw me such exception...

500 TypeError: Cannot read property 'ID' of undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try req.sessionID rather than req.session.ID
there is no such attribute as ID in req.session